# Unable to persist state of a cart (ecommerce website) in localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, react-context

I am trying to persist the state of the items in my cart with the help of local storage. While I am able to save the items in the local storage when an item is added, the cart does not persist when I refresh the page.

I am lost as to where in this code should I implement the "getItem" code to persist the state cart even the page is refreshed. Any help would be appreciated, attaching the code files below.

CartProvider.js

```
import React from "react";
import CartContext from "./cart-context";
import { useReducer, useEffect } from "react";

const defaultCartState = {
  items: [],
  totalAmount: 0,
};

const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  let updatedItem;

  let updatedItems;
   
  if (action.type === "ADD_CART_ITEM") {
    updatedItem = { ...action.item };
    updatedItems = state.items.concat(action.item);
  }
  const newTotalAmount = state.totalAmount + action.item.price;

  const localData = localStorage.getItem("cart");

  return {
    items: updatedItems,
    totalAmount: newTotalAmount,
  };
};

export default function CartProvider(props) {
 
  const [cartState, dispatchCartAction] = useReducer(
    cartReducer,
    defaultCartState
  );

  const addItemToCartHandler = (item) => {
    dispatchCartAction({ type: "ADD_CART_ITEM", item: item });
  };

  const removeItemFromCartHandler = (id) => {
    dispatchCartAction({ type: "REMOVE_CART_ITEM", id: id });
  };

  const cartContext = {
    items: cartState.items,
    totalAmount: cartState.totalAmount,
    addItem: addItemToCartHandler,
    removeItem: removeItemFromCartHandler,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartState.items));
  }, [cartState.items]);

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={cartContext}>
      {props.children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare `useEffect` with no dependency so it will only run once through component life cycle at that time you can check if data exists in localstorage than you set it , check below example.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let items=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    if(items){
     addItemToCartHandler (items)
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: thanks, i'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: worked like a charm but how do I deal with the totalAmount part?

Comment: that you need to figure it out from your code (calculating and dispatching totalAmount)

Comment: the total amount is getting stored as "NaN" for some reason, attaching my code below

to store the items in localStorage
```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartState.items));
    var stringAmount = +cartState.totalAmount;
    localStorage.setItem("totalAmount", stringAmount);
  }, [cartState.items]);
```
fetching items from local storage
```
useEffect(() => {
    let items=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    if(items){
     addItemToCartHandler (items);
     cartState.totalAmount = Number(localStorage.getItem("totalAmount"));
}
```

Comment: sorry this became very messy, will attach the code in separate comments

Comment: STORING ITEMS

`useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartState.items));
    var stringAmount = +cartState.totalAmount;
    localStorage.setItem("totalAmount", stringAmount);
  }, [cartState.items]);`

Comment: FETCHING ITEMS

`useEffect(() => {
    let items=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    if(items){
     addItemToCartHandler (items);

     console.log( typeof( (localStorage.getItem("totalAmount"))));
     console.log(localStorage.getItem("totalAmount"))
     cartState.totalAmount = Number(localStorage.getItem("totalAmount"));

    }`